# upw цвет ButtonPressedBackground

Tags: uwp

Как поменять цвет ButtonPressedBackground, ButtonHoverBackground и т.п. В свойствах самого компонента (объекта) нету, пытался через стили, но в Property такого тоже нет. Можно хотя бы ссылку на то, как это делается, я бы с удовольствием почитал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открываете нужную страницу в `Blend`, правой кнопкой по нужному элементы - `Style - Edit a copy`. И меняете в стиле что захотите.

Или можно просто скопировать нужный стиль из `c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.15063.0\Generic\generic.xaml` и ковырять его. Результат будет тот же.